# (#33) This object does not exist or does not support this action in Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am following https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/.

```
GET graph.facebook.com
  /search?
    q=coffee&
    type=place&
    center=37.76,-122.427&
    distance=1000
```

[Graph API Explorer Screenshot Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Izcr5.png)

I am getting these response:

```
    {
       "error": {
           "message": "(#33) This object does not exist or does not support this action",
           "type": "OAuthException",
           "code": 33,
           "fbtrace_id": "ABMnuhD-PiM0LPKBbRa23ZF"
       }
    }
```

Can anyone tell me the reason for this Exception and how I should fix this?

Comment: Did anyone get any fix for this?